# Visual FoxPro 9 program running in Windows 10 - All labels are missing, odd crashes

Tags: windows, visual-foxpro, delphi-6

A Visual FoxPro 9 program I support is not working on ONE SPECIFIC copy of Windows 10. Other users are working in Windows 10 without issue, but for this one user, all of the form labels are not displaying. Text boxes still work fine.

The program uses some ActiveX controls that are built in Delphi 6, and those are exhibiting similar behavior. Both pieces of the program are also sometimes crashing with divide by zero errors (again, only on this one specific install -- all other users from WinXP to Win10 are running fine).

I've tried compatibility mode and admin mode. I've validated that the install is complete and that the files are not corrupt. Any idea about what might cause this type of issue?

Comment: Wondering if you have checked that one user's display settings against the others.  I ran into a situation where some text wasn't showing properly and I had to play with those settings.

Comment: @Hank Sure enough, the user was at 150% on their scaling setting, which when dropped back to 100% the program began working correctly. I have to assume that the "divide by zero" issues were because the labels were blank (width/height = 0)... so any math used for positioning was calculating against zero. If you want to post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wondering if you have checked that one user's display settings against the others. I ran into a situation where some text wasn't showing properly and I had to play with those settings.

Answer (score 0):

Just got a notification from StackOverflow that this question has been viewed 1000 times, and I realized that the more complicated answer was never posted.

While Hank's suggestion was helpful for a few people, other people continued to crash even after playing with display settings, scales, zooms, and other things. While doing a screen share with one of the people who were crashing, I started comparing the screens that had text with those that did not. The fonts that were showing up were ARIAL, while the missing text was in VERDANA.

Windows 10 did in fact have Verdana installed, but FoxPro and Delphi couldn't display anything in Verdana. Eventually after a bunch of poking around, I found that Windows 10 had a new (possibly 4k compatible font?) for Verdana and forcing a reinstall of the older font package fixed the problem. Not a great "long term" solution, but people aren't crashing anymore... and we're rewriting the entire system for the web.